# find a counter example to the statement $\forall_{x \in C}(\exists_{y \in C}(y \in A) \Rightarrow \neg (x \in B)) .$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint sets, and $C$ be a set of cardinality $3$.

Then find a counter example to the statement $$\forall_{x \in C}(\exists_{y \in C}(y \in A) \Rightarrow \neg (x \in B)) .$$

Find $A =?, \ B= ?, \ C=?$, which construct a counter example of the above statement.

**My approach:**

If we let $A=\Bbb Z^{\large -}$ be the set of negative integers and $B=\Bbb Z^{+}$ be the set of positive integers and let $C=\{ \bar 0, \ \bar 1, \ \bar 2 \}$ be modulo $3$ has cardinality $3$. Also $A \cap B=\emptyset.$

I think this gives us $\forall_{x \in C}(\exists_{y \in C}(y \in A) \Rightarrow  (x \in B))$ because $ \bar 0, \ \bar 1, \ \bar 2$ contains negative as well as positive integers.

But I am not sure.

Can you check it please?

If I am wrong then please give me construct a counter example of the given statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your counter example works, but the negation of $\forall_{x\in C}~(\exists_{ y\in C}~(y\in A)~\Rightarrow~x\not\in B)$ is

$$\exists_{y\in C}(y\in A)~\land~\exists_{x\in C}(x\in B)$$
Since $C$ contains negative as well as positive integers, that the negation is satisfiable, which is indeed a counter example.

Comment: The negation of $\forall x\,\exists y\, (P)$ isn't $\exists x \exists y\,(\neg P).$ The negation of $\forall x\in C\,\exists y\in C\,(y\in A\implies x\not \in B)\;$ is $\;\exists x\in C\,\forall y\in C\,(\neg (y\in A\implies x\not \in B))\;$ which is equivalent to $\exists x\in C\,\forall y\in C\, (y\in A\land x\in B).$ Since there $does$ exist some $x\in C$, this implies $\forall y\in C\,(y\in A)$  and also implies $\exists x\in C\,(x\in B),$ a contradiction, as $A,B$ are disjoint. So the negation is FALSE. There are no counter-examples.

Comment: I rarely down-vote but I did it here.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I think his 'exists' is inside the bracket like this $\forall_{x\in C}~((\exists_{ y\in C}~y\in A)~\Rightarrow~x\not\in B)$, if otherwise, what you said is correct

Comment: Since the question is asking for counter examples, that I suppose it should be the first case

Comment: And the way the question writing the quantifier is more like a predicate, for example $\forall_x(P(x)),\exists_x(P(x))$, that $\exists_{y\in C}~(y\in A)$ is  acturally one-thing inside the bracket

Comment: I removed my down-vote. But the way the Q appears is according to what I said. I agree there seem to be extra brackets that weren't intended, which  changes the Q.