# Disjunctive introduction rule ( i.e OR intro ) for predicate logic :freely introducing OR inside a quantified sentence?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

While I was trying to answer this question : 
[find a counter example to the statement $\forall_{x \in C}(\exists_{y \in C}(y \in A) \Rightarrow \neg (x \in B)) .$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416208/find-a-counter-example-to-the-statement-forall-x-in-c-exists-y-in-cy)

I asked myself whether this move is legal in predicate logic :

(1) There is some x that does not belong to C

therefore

(2) There is some x such that  ( x does not belong to C ***OR  whatever*** )

Is it legal to use " OR intro" inside a quantified formula? Does a quantified formula remain true in case I really add " whatever" I want as disjunct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes because for (1) to be true means that (1) holds in all models. But (2) is *weaker* than (1) in each model separately, so this move is indeed legal (as long as *whatever* is a valid formula in the language, of course).